# How to sorting multi array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have one multi dimensional array, i want to be sort array based on **SequenceID** in the every array nested array, based on sequence number wise like 1,2,3,4,5,6 like SequenceID wise data display. How to do this please any one help on this .
My array data is below .

```
<?php

$dataarray=  array(

            "CAR_DATA" => array(
                   "SNo" => 1607,
                   "SRRequestID" => 22666,
                   "AncillarySearchID"=>3333,
                   "car_data_line" => array (
                           "QuoteID" => 1607,
                           "SequenceID" => 5
                        ) 
                     ),
            "FLIGHT_DATA" => array(
                "SNo" => 1212,
                "SRRequestID" => 2222,
                "FLightSearchID"=>3333,
                "flight_data_line" => array (
                        "QuoteID" => 3222,
                        "SequenceID" => 2
               )
             ),

            "FLIGHT_DATA" => array(
                    "SNo" => 3222,
                    "SRRequestID" => 2222,
                    "FLightSearchID"=>3333,
                    "flight_data_line" => array (
                            "QuoteID" => 3222,
                            "SequenceID" => 1
                   )
                 ),


            "HOTEL_DATA" => array(
                    "SNo" => 343,
                    "SRRequestID" => 212,
                    "HotelSearchID"=>3434,
                    "hotel_data_line" => array (
                        "QuoteID" => 456,
                        "SequenceID" => 3
                   )
                 ),

            "HOTEL_DATA" => array(
                    "SNo" => 32,
                    "SRRequestID" => 3333,
                    "HotelSearchID"=>343,
                    "hotel_data_line" => array (
                        "QuoteID" => 121,
                        "SequenceID" => 6
                   )
                 ),

                 "HOTEL_DATA" => array(
                    "SNo" => 344,
                    "SRRequestID" => 34343,
                    "HotelSearchID"=>4433,
                    "hotel_data_line" => array (
                        "QuoteID" => 22222,
                        "SequenceID" => 4
                   )
                 ),

             );

        echo "<pre>";print_r($dataarray);
        ?>
```

Expected out put is below .

```
<?php

$ExpectedOutPutData=  array(


            "FLIGHT_DATA" => array(
                    "SNo" => 3222,
                    "SRRequestID" => 2222,
                    "FLightSearchID"=>3333,
                    "flight_data_line" => array (
                            "QuoteID" => 3222,
                            "SequenceID" => 1
                   )
                 ),

            "FLIGHT_DATA" => array(
                "SNo" => 1212,
                "SRRequestID" => 2222,
                "FLightSearchID"=>3333,
                "flight_data_line" => array (
                        "QuoteID" => 3222,
                        "SequenceID" => 2
               )
             ),

            "HOTEL_DATA" => array(
                    "SNo" => 343,
                    "SRRequestID" => 212,
                    "HotelSearchID"=>3434,
                    "hotel_data_line" => array (
                        "QuoteID" => 456,
                        "SequenceID" => 3
                   )
                 ),

            "HOTEL_DATA" => array(
                "SNo" => 344,
                "SRRequestID" => 34343,
                "HotelSearchID"=>4433,
                "hotel_data_line" => array (
                    "QuoteID" => 22222,
                    "SequenceID" => 4
               )
             ),

           "CAR_DATA" => array(
               "SNo" => 1607,
               "SRRequestID" => 22666,
               "AncillarySearchID"=>3333,
               "car_data_line" => array (
                       "QuoteID" => 1607,
                       "SequenceID" => 5
                    ) 
                 ),

            "HOTEL_DATA" => array(
                    "SNo" => 32,
                    "SRRequestID" => 3333,
                    "HotelSearchID"=>343,
                    "hotel_data_line" => array (
                        "QuoteID" => 121,
                        "SequenceID" => 6
                   )
                 )
             );


        ?>
```

Here challenge is i have  CAR_DATA array one time and FLIGHT_DATA array 2 times and HOTEL_DATA array 3 times came in this example. i need with in these nested array is **SequenceID** based on serial number wise data showing.

```
 Original code 

    <?php 

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [flight_data] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [SNo] => 33052
                                        [Flight_Search_ID] => 32955
                                        [SR_Request_ID] => 44331
                                        [quote_flight_data] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [ID] => 11652
                                                        [ReqID] => 44331
                                                        [SearchID] => 32955
                                                        [QuoteID] => 3978
                                                        [SequenceID] => 5
                                                        [QuoteGeneratedID] => R44331-1464
                                                        [RequestID] => 44331
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                        [QMergeId] => 
                        [BookingDate] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [flight_data] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [SNo] => 33052
                                        [Flight_Search_ID] => 32955
                                        [SR_Request_ID] => 44331
                                        [quote_flight_data] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [ID] => 11653
                                                        [ReqID] => 44331
                                                        [SearchID] => 32955
                                                        [QuoteID] => 3979
                                                        [SequenceID] => 3
                                                        [QuoteGeneratedID] => R44331-1464
                                                        [RequestID] => 44331
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                        [QMergeId] => 
                        [BookingDate] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [flight_data] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [SNo] => 33052
                                        [Flight_Search_ID] => 32955
                                        [SR_Request_ID] => 44331
                                        [quote_flight_data] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [ID] => 11652
                                                        [ReqID] => 44331
                                                        [SearchID] => 32955
                                                        [QuoteID] => 3980
                                                        [SequenceID] => 2
                                                        [QuoteGeneratedID] => R44331-1464
                                                        [RequestID] => 44331
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                        [QMergeId] => 
                        [BookingDate] => 20200317
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [flight_data] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [SNo] => 33052
                                        [Flight_Search_ID] => 32955
                                        [SR_Request_ID] => 44331
                                        [quote_flight_data] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [ID] => 11653
                                                        [ReqID] => 44331
                                                        [SearchID] => 32955
                                                        [QuoteID] => 3981
                                                        [SequenceID] => 6
                                                        [QuoteGeneratedID] => R44331-1464
                                                        [RequestID] => 44331
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )

                            )
                        [QMergeId] => 
                        [BookingDate] => 20200317
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [hotel_data] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [hid] => 16014
                                        [SNo] => 16019
                                        [Hotel_Search_ID] => 16014
                                        [SR_Request_ID] => 44331
                                        [quote_hotel_data] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [QuoteID] => 3943
                                                        [SequenceID] => 1
                                                        [QuoteGeneratedID] => R44331-1464
                                                        [RequestID] => 44331
                                                        [SearchID] => 16014
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                        [QMergeId] => 
                        [BookingDate] => 20200317
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [hotel_data] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [hid] => 16014
                                        [SNo] => 16019
                                        [Hotel_Search_ID] => 16014
                                        [SR_Request_ID] => 44331
                                        [quote_hotel_data] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [QuoteID] => 3944
                                                        [SequenceID] => 4
                                                        [QuoteGeneratedID] => R44331-1464
                                                        [RequestID] => 44331
                                                        [SearchID] => 16014
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                        [QMergeId] => 
                        [BookingDate] => 20200317
                    )

            )

    )

    ?>
```

> ORIGINAL DATA OUTPUR AFTER JSON ENCODE AND DECODE

```
$array= Array
(
    [flight_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SNo] => 32999
                    [Flight_Search_ID] => 32902
                    [SR_Request_ID] => 44232
                    [quote_flight_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [ID] => 11537
                                    [ReqID] => 44232
                                    [SearchID] => 32902
                                    [QuoteID] => 3921
                                    [SequenceID] => 2
                                    [QuoteGeneratedID] => R44232-1426
                                    [RequestID] => 44232
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [QMergeId] => 
    [BookingDate] => 20200416
)


Array
(
    [flight_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SNo] => 32999
                    [Flight_Search_ID] => 32902
                    [SR_Request_ID] => 44232
                    [quote_flight_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [ID] => 11537
                                    [ReqID] => 44232
                                    [SearchID] => 32902
                                    [QuoteID] => 3921
                                    [SequenceID] => 1
                                    [QuoteGeneratedID] => R44232-1426
                                    [RequestID] => 44232
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [QMergeId] => 
    [BookingDate] => 20200416
)

Array
(
    [hotel_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SNo] => 32999
                    [Flight_Search_ID] => 32902
                    [SR_Request_ID] => 44232
                    [quote_hotel_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [ID] => 11537
                                    [ReqID] => 44232
                                    [SearchID] => 32902
                                    [QuoteID] => 3921
                                    [SequenceID] => 4
                                    [QuoteGeneratedID] => R44232-1426
                                    [RequestID] => 44232
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [QMergeId] => 
    [BookingDate] => 20200416
)

Array
(
    [hotel_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SNo] => 32999
                    [Flight_Search_ID] => 32902
                    [SR_Request_ID] => 44232
                    [quote_hotel_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [ID] => 11537
                                    [ReqID] => 44232
                                    [SearchID] => 32902
                                    [QuoteID] => 3921
                                    [SequenceID] => 3
                                    [QuoteGeneratedID] => R44232-1426
                                    [RequestID] => 44232
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [QMergeId] => 
    [BookingDate] => 20200416
)

Array
(
    [car_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SNo] => 32999
                    [Flight_Search_ID] => 32902
                    [SR_Request_ID] => 44232
                    [quote_car_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [ID] => 11537
                                    [ReqID] => 44232
                                    [SearchID] => 32902
                                    [QuoteID] => 3921
                                    [SequenceID] => 5
                                    [QuoteGeneratedID] => R44232-1426
                                    [RequestID] => 44232
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [QMergeId] => 
    [BookingDate] => 20200416
)
```

Comment: I am unable to understand the sorting sequence, which index value used to sort data as well as what's the order `asc` or `desc`?

Comment: my original code is edited above please check and search with **SequenceID** in my original code, based on sequence number like 1,2,3,4,5..data need to show

Comment: A problem with your original data is that you have multiple items with the same key (`FLIGHT_DATA` for example) so this will not work. The `print_r($dataarray);` only shows 3 items of data as the others are lost as thy are overwritten.

Comment: @NigelRen what you said exactly correct , yes i have multiple items with same key like `FLIGHT_DATA` , `HOTEL_DATA` , `CAR_DATA` . what is solution for this problem. But my manager forcing me last 2 days onwards . must and should i have to do please any other solution .

Comment: Can you change how you generate this array?

Comment: you need to generate array with different keys not duplicate.

Comment: my Original data coming from controller `$data['dataarray']['CAR_DATA'] = $this->quote_modelv2->GetCardata(parameters);
$data['dataarray']['FLIGHT_DATA'] = $this->quote_modelv2->GetFlightdata(parameters);
$data['dataarray']['HOTEL_DATA'] = $this->quote_modelv2->GetHoteldata(parameters);`     here data getting from 3 querys , but i want to display based on serial number wise .

Comment: Can you change that to `$data['dataarray']['CAR_DATA'][]` (with the end brackets) - add this to all of the types.

Comment: For example if i change the data like this `$data['dataarray']['CAR_DATA'][] = $this->quote_modelv2->GetCardata(parameters); $data['dataarray']['FLIGHT_DATA'][]= $this->quote_modelv2->GetFlightdata(parameters); $data['dataarray']['HOTEL_DATA'][] = $this->quote_modelv2->GetHoteldata(parameters);`  after how to display data based on sequence ID number wise please

Comment: Can you update the question with the new data, check that your `print_r()` displays all of the data.

Comment: okay please 5 minutes i will update the question with data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would be able to make your array as the way that would work. Because you've **duplicate keys** in your array. You can't preserve keys becasue PHP will keep the last one. So your array should be in the following way:

```
<?php

$dataArray=  array(
    array(
        "CAR_DATA" => array(
            "SNo" => 1607,
            "SRRequestID" => 22666,
            "AncillarySearchID"=>3333,
            "car_data_line" => array (
                "QuoteID" => 1607,
                "SequenceID" => 5
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        "FLIGHT_DATA" => array(
            "SNo" => 1212,
            "SRRequestID" => 2222,
            "FLightSearchID"=>3333,
            "flight_data_line" => array (
                "QuoteID" => 3222,
                "SequenceID" => 2
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        "FLIGHT_DATA" => array(
            "SNo" => 3222,
            "SRRequestID" => 2222,
            "FLightSearchID"=>3333,
            "flight_data_line" => array (
                "QuoteID" => 3222,
                "SequenceID" => 1
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        "HOTEL_DATA" => array(
            "SNo" => 343,
            "SRRequestID" => 212,
            "HotelSearchID"=>3434,
            "hotel_data_line" => array (
                "QuoteID" => 456,
                "SequenceID" => 3
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        "HOTEL_DATA" => array(
            "SNo" => 32,
            "SRRequestID" => 3333,
            "HotelSearchID"=>343,
            "hotel_data_line" => array (
                "QuoteID" => 121,
                "SequenceID" => 6
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        "HOTEL_DATA" => array(
            "SNo" => 344,
            "SRRequestID" => 34343,
            "HotelSearchID"=>4433,
            "hotel_data_line" => array (
                "QuoteID" => 22222,
                "SequenceID" => 4
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

Next up let's make a new array based on **SequenceID** as the keys. Then sort the array using `ksort()` function. That's it.

```
<?php

function sortArrayBySequenceID($array) {

    $new = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($value['CAR_DATA']['car_data_line']['SequenceID'])) {
            $new[$value['CAR_DATA']['car_data_line']['SequenceID']] = $array[$key];
        } elseif (isset($value['FLIGHT_DATA']['flight_data_line']['SequenceID'])) {
            $new[$value['FLIGHT_DATA']['flight_data_line']['SequenceID']] = $array[$key];
        } elseif (isset($value['HOTEL_DATA']['hotel_data_line']['SequenceID'])) {
            $new[$value['HOTEL_DATA']['hotel_data_line']['SequenceID']] = $array[$key];
        }

    }

    // Sorts the newly made array based on key
    ksort($new);

    return $new;
}

print_r(sortArrayBySequenceID($dataArray));
```

Comment: Thanks it working , but i want to be get from my Original data . can you please check my **Original Data** in my post , i want result from that data . Please help on this

Comment: Well, you **Original data**  may be the result of `print_r($some_variable)`. Can you be able to show the data using this snippet `$array = json_decode(json_encode($some_variable), true);`?

Comment: `foreach($originalData as $qq){
 foreach($qq as $q){
  
  $array = json_decode(json_encode($q), true);
  echo "<pre>";print_r($array);echo "</pre>";
 }
}`  printing this data using above code . i got below snippet

Comment: please check in my question updated original output   **ORIGINAL DATA OUTPUR AFTER JSON ENCODE AND DECODE**

Comment: Please check this link [https://pastebin.com/kxaDb5Cv](https://pastebin.com/kxaDb5Cv)

Comment: this data i want to display based on SequenceID wise in each array .Please help on this

Comment: Sorry ,Please check once again pastebin. Yes **SequenceID** is unique. Some time may be multiple SequenceID  if will come i need to display any order if same SequenceID id .  [https://pastebin.com/YUuPZALT](https://pastebin.com/YUuPZALT)

Comment: Some times SequenceID may not Unique , same SequenceID will come multiple times , in this case any order we can show the data if the same SequenceID will repeate,remain all will display order wise

Comment: Unclexo ..Can you please tell me other way if SequenceID is not Unique, for example SequenceID 2 getting 2 times remain all will come sequence Order like 1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6 if it will come like this what is the solution for this ,Please tell me @Unclexo

Comment: Here is your data format that may satisfy you. Check that out here https://3v4l.org/uMqT0 and try to understand.

Comment: unclexo , It`s working if SequenceID is **Unique**, if not its not working . Is there any other solution plz ..??

Comment: Well, PHP doesn't keep same indices as key. So what you've to do is keep the SequenceIDs into an array as I did in case of index/key 3. Notice index 3 has two arrays. Because their SequenceIDs are same which is 3. See the output https://3v4l.org/uMqT0  here carefully.

Comment: After followed your way am getting this output for non unique SequenceIDs ,Please check Unclexo .. [https://pastebin.com/f7sX8TVa](https://pastebin.com/f7sX8TVa)

Comment: Yup! that's quite correct. You see there are 3 items in index 1 of the array because  those 3 items have same SequenceIDs which is 1. I said you can't set same index twice or more in php array. I hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks , yes i understand but in this case how to solve this problem ? Any other way . Means if same SequenceID will come more than one time

Comment: Well, you may do this way if that satisfies you anyhow. Check out the link https://3v4l.org/5uv25

Comment: Again am getting wrong data after using your code ,Please once check [https://pastebin.com/kjQHCnNL](https://pastebin.com/kjQHCnNL)

Comment: I'v shown you what is possible so far as PHP's array works. Thanks

Comment: i can not understand if SequenceID is coming not unique ,means like 1,2,4,5,3,7,6,this . how to solve problem in this case. one of my senior given suggestion we have **$arrays** data sort based on sequenceID in for loop .

Comment: Well, my last code in here https://3v4l.org/5uv25 would do `3`, `3-1`, `3-2` etc. if the SequenceID 3 exists 3 times. Meaning 1, 2, 3, 3-1, 3-2, 4, 5 and so on.

Comment: Good , based on your logic how to print data in `for loop` or `for each` loop in your last code if i take all the output data in one variable ?

Comment: Please check after using your logic i got this output data, how to print in for loop ?? [https://pastebin.com/yyGcFur3](https://pastebin.com/yyGcFur3)

Comment: @ParikshithChowdam see, it's a place for solving a problem where one gets stuck. But not something the way you asked for. I hope you understand.

Comment: ..i have one doubt here please .. requirement changed based on product wise need to show data .